# Sanitize helper in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sanitize

Can you explain about this

```
2.1.3 :015 > ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize '<b>test</b>'
 => "<b>test</b>"
```

The result is not like it should be as said in documentation http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize

But this is correct

```
2.1.3 :017 > ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize('<b>test</b>', tags: [])
 => "test"
```

I have no WhiteListSanitizer in my configs. Maybe Rails have anywhere WhiteListSanitizer by default? How can I find it? Or maybe I something is not understand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, it is working exactly like you would expect. The `sanitize` helper is designed to keep benign html tags and remove potentially harmful tags.

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize("<b>test</b>")
=> "<b>test</b>" 

ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize("<script>test</script>")
=> ""
```

You can adjust the global settings of the sanitize method  in `config/application.rb`.

```
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = ['b']
```

Then you get:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize("<b>test</b>")
=> "test"
```